# ListView split row cells in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, merge, cell

※ Add Info
I forgot to tell one thing is each list item have to get their own color (refer image)
[Click Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEgeo.png)
I already tried to using stackpanel, but it coudln't display the color for each items.

---

I'm trying to find the way split the specific row in wpf.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtK1s.png)

The following attachment is the format what i want to make by wpf.

To merge Row is not what I want.(becacuse I want to split the row data in one instance)

The data(1~3-3) is member property of each Instance.

Does anybody can solve this problem?
I'll look forward to you guys answer.

thank you

Comment: Add a `DataTemplate` to that Column containing a `Stackpanel` and your Bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataGrid instead like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" Width="400" Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Addresses">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address1}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address2}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address3}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please change the bindings of the columns with your data context properties.

Comment: It works, but that's not what I want.

0
down vote
favorite
forgot to tell one thing is each list item have to get their own color (refer image at the title) I already tried to using stackpanel, but it coudln't display the color for each items.